# 1995 Ford F-250 - Starter continues to run until the batteries are dead

Tags: ford, diesel, starter, f-250

Have a '95 Ford F250 with the 7.3l diesel. Starter just quit working one day. I changed the solenoid and the key lock barrel on the steering column. Now it will turn over but won't stop. Starter motor will continue to run until the batteries are dead. I've been told there are a couple of other relays in the ignition system.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the thin control wire from the starter solenoid while the starter is running.  If it continues to run, this would indicate a fault with the solenoid.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your ignition switch is bad. Its common to replace it when you replace the key lock barrel.

Why does it sound bad to me?

If broken internally, the switch will move from off to on and to run, but will not recoil back to the on position. Don't replace anything else until you look into this.

This is not only annoying but a big safety issue as well.